# How to add logic to classview

Tags: python, django

I have the following class view:

```
class RegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = forms.RegisterForm
    template_name = 'register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('platforms')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
        user = authenticate(username=form.instance.username, password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
        login(self.request, user)
        return response
```

How would I add in the following statement to the above, which I would do in a normal function?

```
def normal_register_function(request):
    if request.user is not None:
        return redirect('home')
    # register logic
    return render(request, 'register.html', data)
```

Comment: You can add that logic in the get  method of the CBV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
class RegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = forms.RegisterForm
    template_name = 'register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('platforms')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user is not None:
            return redirect('home')
        # register logic
        return render(request, 'register.html', data)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
        user = authenticate(username=form.instance.username, password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
        login(self.request, user)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dispatch method as described in http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/:

```
class RegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    # other methods

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('home')
        return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```